# Create site in Netbox from csv with Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, netbox

I'm trying to create sites in Netbox based on a CSV file. Since I'm adding an ID to the site name, I don't want the site to be created when there is no ID specified for the site. In this case, CHI and STO will be created but BER not.

I've tried to put

```
when: {{ item.ID }} not ''
```

before and after the loop int the second task but without success.

CSV:

```
sitename,ID,location
CHI,101,Chicago
BER,,Berlin
STO,103,Stockholm
```

Playbook:

```
tasks:
  - name: "read sites from csv"
    community.general.read_csv:
      path: sites.csv
      delimiter: ','
    register: sitelist
    delegate_to: localhost

  - name: "create/update sites in netbox"
    netbox.netbox.netbox_site:
      netbox_url: https://url
      netbox_token: token
      data:
        name: "{{ item.sitename }}-{{ item.ID}}"
        physical_address: "{{ item.location }}"
    loop: "{{ sitelist.list }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to write your test like this:

```
  tasks:
  - name: "read sites from csv"
    community.general.read_csv:
      path: sites.csv
      delimiter: ','
    register: sitelist
    delegate_to: localhost

  - debug:
      msg: "name: {{ item.sitename }}-{{ item.ID}}, physical_address: {{ item.location }}"
    loop: "{{ sitelist.list }}"
    when: item.ID != ''
```

result:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'sitename': 'CHI', 'ID': '101', 'location': 'Chicago'}) => {
    "msg": "name: CHI-101, physical_address: Chicago"
}
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'sitename': 'BER', 'ID': '', 'location': 'Berlin'}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'sitename': 'STO', 'ID': '103', 'location': 'Stockholm'}) => {
    "msg": "name: STO-103, physical_address: Stockholm"
}
```